# How to tell if Cassandra sec. indexes are too overburdened?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I am having a problem with Cassandra query timeouts that came up after increasing total data from ~2MB to about 460MB.

I am throwing some queries which are taking even 6 minutes to resolve. And that was after I set `rpc_timeout_in_ms: 1000` on both nodes. I did that because I thought timeouts were possibly associated with a  `get_indexed_slices` query that gets exhausted and finds nothing.

Each row has at most 10 columns now with barely 4 bytes in ea. col.

Queries are  basically  `min_val < my_column  AND my_column < max_val  AND dummy_col = 0`

I have two Amazon Datastax AMI nodes w/ replication factor =2 .

Here is my partial  `nodetool cfstats` output .

```
$ nodetool cfstats -h localhost
Keyspace: Keyspace1
    Read Count: 12403801
    Read Latency: 0.08655620273172715 ms.
    Write Count: 1500181
    Write Latency: 0.12406482817739993 ms.
    Pending Tasks: 0
            Column Family: col_family
            SSTable count: 3
            Space used (live): 488592615
            Space used (total): 488592615
            Number of Keys (estimate): 1454976
            Memtable Columns Count: 0
            Memtable Data Size: 0
            Memtable Switch Count: 26
            Read Count: 12403801
            Read Latency: NaN ms.
            Write Count: 1500181
            Write Latency: NaN ms.
            Pending Tasks: 0
            Bloom Filter False Postives: 10879
            Bloom Filter False Ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom Filter Space Used: 2731728
            Key cache capacity: 200000
            Key cache size: 200000
            Key cache hit rate: NaN
            Row cache: disabled
            Compacted row minimum size: 180
            Compacted row maximum size: 310
            Compacted row mean size: 310
```

**UPDATE**

One thing that helped was that I tried to make sure my row keys were sequential. Prior, my rowkeys were timestamps in milliseconds. These were very sparse.

I did not calculate the exact improvement, but it was noticeable.